Unable to fit MeanEncoder. error 'Index' object has no attribute 'infer_objects'
I am trying to run this code in Jupyter Notebook
import pandas as pd
from feature_engine.encoding import MeanEncoder

X = pd.DataFrame(dict(x1 = [1,2,3,4,5], x2 = ["c", "c", "c", "b", "a"]))

y = pd.Series([0,1,1,1,0])
me = MeanEncoder()
me.fit(X,y)
me.transform(X)

running that returns the following error message :
228 counts.index = counts.index.infer_objects()

AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'infer_objects'

I would expect MeanEncoder to encode x1 and x2 according to y.

What version of pandas are you using?
